# Is it possible for state and federal taxes to already have been removed on a 1099-MISC?

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, form-1099-misc

I am a PhD student and receive a stipend from the university. I get a 1099-MISC for that money. On the 1099-MISC this year, there's an amount listed in box 4 and box 16 for federal and state, respectively. I thought that these amounts were the taxes *already taken out* of the money I received, because at the start of the year I filled out another form saying that I wanted certain withholdings taken out as time went along. I didn't want to have to pay a lump sum for the whole year.

I'm asking because H&R Block online is telling me that I owe state taxes, even though it looks like, according to box 16, I've already paid a larger amount than that to the state. But I haven't been able to report the amount in box 16 anywhere, and similar for box 4. I haven't been able to enter this information.

My questions are:

1. Are the amounts in those boxes taxes that have already been removed?
2. If they are, how do I report these totals? When I entered the information from the 1099-MISC, it only asked for the total, and didn't ask for (what I thought were) the taxes already taken out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are the amounts in those boxes taxes that have already been removed?

Yes.

> If they are, how do I report these totals? When I entered the information from the 1099-MISC, it only asked for the total, and didn't ask for (what I thought were) the taxes already taken out.

It should appear on your 1040 line 64 (and similar line on your State tax return). If the program doesn't ask for all the 1099 fields (which is stupid), you can add it as additional taxes paid in the Credits section, somewhere in the area where they ask about estimated payments etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about this, but [found this link](http://community.hrblock.com/t5/DIY-Products/1099-MISC-Box-4/td-p/60043#.VS0bIyNVhBc) which suggests for H&R Block specifically:

> I kept searching and I found the section. It's at the end in the Credits section under 'other backup withholding'. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.